# Cannot type into text/input field with electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

So I am developing an app (calendar) with electron. I have made this menu where you can add new events and so on. And I want the user to be able to enter the title of their event into a textbox/input field. But when I create the element, I cannot type anything into it..? This is how i have set it up:

```
var inputField = document.createElement("input");
    inputField.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputField.setAttribute("value","Title");
var container = document.getElementById("mainCont");
    container.appendChild(inputField);
```

Why isn't this working..? I have also tried wrapping everything up in a paragraph tag, but to no avail.

In advance, thanks.

Comment: This is working fine to me, please can you do a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue.

Comment: not for me.. Can it be the api?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: When i do it in jsfiddle everything is working fint tho

Comment: This should be related to Electron itself, but I cannot help you without more info.

Comment: Thats what i thought

Answer (score 2):

Oh well, I found the answer.. It turns out that I have to 'focus' the input element when using electron. The solution:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could solve it, by setting

```
focusable: true
```

in your `BrowserWindow({})` definitions.